# Php :Print array inside multi select

Tags: php

I want to print the below array inside multi select ;

this is my html code for multi select .

```
<select name="user_email[]" size="17" style="margin-top:8px; height:256px;" multiple="multiple" class="wiidth300px textBoxStyle removePadding removeMargin externale_users" value="">
```

This is my array:
$test =array ( [0] => abc@example.com [1] => def@example.com );
i want to print the elements of array html multi select.

Comment: This is basic PHP. What have you tried?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <select multiple>
```

is what you do to select more than one.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have to work a lot
you can do this like following:

```
<?php $array = Array ('kagava,kagava@manutd.com','evra,evra@manutd.com')?>
<select>
<?php
 foreach($array as $index=>$email)
 {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $email?>"><?php echo $email?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

this will work surely

Comment: In this can i select multiple options at a time...?

Comment: You have to add `multiple` attribute to `<select>`

Comment: select is same buddy your select is good. you can remain attribute here also. this will work. try it

Comment: @R.V.P I for one think you accepted the wrong answer. All you needed to do was add the word "multiple" to `<select` in this answer as so `<select multiple>` since Deepak did all the work.

Comment: @DeepakManwal Going to +1 your answer.

Comment: Its ok dear finally you got. I am happy. Best of luck